# How to read environment variable set by envinject in Java?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

I am running a Jenkins instance hosted by Cloudbees.  I installed the Jenkins EnvInject plugin and I added a Pre-Build step.  I added a variable under "Properties Content":

`CERT_HOME=/private/{my-domain-name}/dev`

The `CERT_HOME` path and actual certificates are under the WebDAV directory that Cloudbees provides.

In a JUnit test, I try to access the environment variable like this:

`private static final String CERT_HOME = System.getenv("CERT_HOME");`

However, it returns null.

Under the build, I do see the environment variable:

`CERT_HOME=/private/{my-domain-name}/dev`

How do I read an environment variable in my JUnit test that I set using the EnvInject plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven surefire tries to give you a clean environment within the forked process, have a look at using [`environmentVariables`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#environmentVariables) with `${env.CERT_HOME}` to try passing it through

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My env vars were global to all builds so I went to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System and set my env var there.  However, the approach you outline works for more granular support.